# Android Gridview and Button OnItemclick

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

Here is my buttonAdapter class that i think is accurate:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Context; 
import android.graphics.Color; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.GridView;

public class ButtonAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
    private Context mContext; 
    public String [] fName = { "File 1", "File 2", "Roflcopters"};

    // Gets the context so it can be used later 
    public ButtonAdapter(Context c) { mContext = c; }

    // Total number of things contained within the adapter 
    public int getCount () { return 8; }

    // Require for structure, not really used in my code. 
    public Object getItem (int position) {  return null; }

    // Require for structure, not really used in my code. Can be used to get the id of an item in the adapter for manual control. 
    public long getItemId (int position) { return position; }

    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){     
        Button btn;         
        if (convertView == null) {      // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes      
            btn = new Button (mContext);
            btn.setLayoutParams (new GridView.LayoutParams (190, 190));
            btn.setPadding (1, 1, 1, 1);    
        } else {        
            btn = (Button) convertView;
        }       
      // btn.setText(filesnames[position]);   
      // filenames is an array of strings    
      //btn.setTextColor (Color.WHITE);
      //btn.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.sample_2);  
      //btn.setBackgroundColor (Color.BLACK);     
      btn.setHighlightColor(Color.GREEN);    
      btn.setId (position);

      return btn; 
    } 
}
```

Here is my home class. I can't get the onItemClick to work out. What am I doing wrong here:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.AdapterView; 
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener; 
import android.widget.GridView; 
import android.widget.Toast;

public class home extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE1 = "com.example.text.MESSAGE";

    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_home);    

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById (R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter (new ButtonAdapter (this));     

        /*gridview.setOnItemClickListener (new OnItemClickListener () {
           public void onItemClick (AdapterView <?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {          
            Toast.makeText (home.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, alarm.class);       
            String message = "Position:" + position;            
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE1, message);        
            startActivity (intent);         
            }     
        });   
     * */    
     }

    @Override 
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView <?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {  
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, alarm.class);
        String message = "Position:" + position;        
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE1, message);        
        startActivity (intent);  
    }
}
```

The onItemClick doesn't work and neither does the commented 'setOnItemClickListener' when it isn't commented out and 'onItemClick' is commented. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you tell me how your ui looks like or what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 5):

If `GridView, ListView` have click able controls like BUtton, then `onItemClick` will not fired.
You need to implement `Button Click listener` in your  `getView` method of the adapter.

like

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button btn;
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                // attributes btn = new Button (mContext);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(190, 190));
        btn.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
    } else {
        btn = (Button) convertView;
    } // btn.setText(filesnames[position]); // filenames is an array of
        // strings //btn.setTextColor (Color.WHITE);
    // btn.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.sample_2);
    // btn.setBackgroundColor (Color.BLACK);
    btn.setHighlightColor(Color.GREEN);
    btn.setId(position);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Handle the click here

        }
    });
    return btn;

}
```

Comment: Now what's the deal? It seems like my intent can't accept arguments? Why not? 
 
 btn.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener () {

  
 @Override
 public void onClick (View v) {

 // Toast msg = Toast.makeText (mContext, "Position:" + slot, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 // msg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, msg.getXOffset() / 2, msg.getYOffset() / 2);
 // msg.show();
   
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnAlarm.class);
      String message = "Position:" + slot;
      intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
      mContext.startActivity(intent);
  }});

 return btn;
}

Comment: which `argument` it does not accept? `position` make it `final`

Comment: I'm trying to delete items from the gridview now. BaseAdapter.remove (position) isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this line in the root layout of GridView items:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Then `onItemClickListener.onItemClick()` will not fire when you tap on subviews which OnClickListener has been defined for them separately.

Comment: Adding this to my grid view cell solved the issue. Both the button AND the grid cell became clickable separately. (Without it, just the button was clickable.)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested that Set Button.onClickListener() (in API 15) won't solve the problem.

So the GridView will not trigger onItemClick if it contains **clickable** views.

You can use ImageView instead Button.

Answer (score -1):

i have the same problem when i was trying to implement `onitemclick` on `gridview` where filled with button. Because the button is stealing the focus of each space on `gridview`, you have to give the inflated button `android:focusable="false"` . however, the button is taking up almost entire space inside a grid, so you have to click the very edge of the button to trigger `onitemclick` call-back. i am suggesting you can set `onclick` or use image and designe it like a button.